# How to set up an OAuth credential with existing API keys with same SHA-1 and package name for Android?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I added logo for my OAuth Consent screen and Google want to verify it. I tried to prepare it for verification but when I want to submit I am getting this information:

```
You need to set up an OAuth credential for this project before you can submit for verification
```

Ok, I go to credentials, click Create credential, I fill all forms and when I want to create I am getting this error:

```
The request failed because the Android package name and fingerprint are already in use
```

How to do it without removing API keys?
I will be glad if I could remove logo but I try to find how to do it and I found it's impossible without removing API keys.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error you can’t have 2 projects of the same package name. If you want to delete the same also it takes a few days to get deleted fully from developers' console.

**Try Below Solutions:**

**Solution 1 :** Try to create a new project with a different package name.

**Solution 2:** Try to generate a new SHA-1 key by custom signing the application by generating a signed apk from the Android studio.

Please refer to the [Signin APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually) for more information.